# Extremely Loud Drawers (deep drawers with slider extension)

Tags: drawers

UPD: The link is updated with pictures of the drawer out and shows the sliders.

We recently moved into a new apartment, and facing a unique issue with the bathroom drawers. Every time we open or close them, there's this loud noise that sounds like they're hitting something. We've tried discussing it with the landlord and realtor/property manager (the realtor tried to install bumpers which helped a little with when you close the drawer but when you open it it's still the same) and, unfortunately, they claim there's nothing more they can do about it.

I've recorded a video to better illustrate the problem (note, the sound in real life is much much louder than on the video): [[Video](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zcW7hBTY8yK4D_BtN0jdymFy5nuZTJ37?usp=drive_link)]

If anyone has experienced something similar or has any DIY tips on how to fix this or who we should reach out to, we would greatly appreciate your help! We really want to use the drawers without waking up the entire building.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Do a better job than the realtor at finding what's hitting what, and add felt there. Or,  use some self-control when operating them.

Comment: Haven't watched the video, but I'd suggest removing all but one drawer, figuring out how to stick your head or hand in there, then close it (gently) to feel or see what it's hitting on. Once you know where it's hitting, you can work on determining how to go about fixing it. Also, please [edit] your title to ask a summary question. We know you're "seeking advice" and that you "need help!", or you wouldn't be here. :D Taking the [tour] and reading up on how to [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) will help, too.

Comment: Thank you! Trying to do a better job by trying to find a solution and no matter how slow and controlling we open the drawers, they always make a loud sound because of the extension (these are deep drawers with extensions).

Comment: The video link says "Access Denied".

Comment: So, you probably need felt or rubber where the extentions hit the rest of the slider, probably on both ends. [Edit] in some pictures of one of your drawers removed, and the slider where it's removed from.

Comment: A picture of the drawer slide may help, as well as the interior of the cabinet with a drawer removed.

Comment: I changed viewing permissions for the video, should be accessible now!

Answer (score 1):

Some drawer slides have a soft-close mechanism as an extra part of the slide to control closing noise. Your bathroom drawer slides are probably broken, and are not engaging the soft-close mechanism correctly, or the soft-close mechanism is damaged.

Or the drawer slide is too long and is hitting the back of the cabinet.

Comment: Thank you! We'll check on the soft-close mechanism!

Comment: I think Triplefault is onto something here.  The slider mechanism has a double bar, and the noise is happening when it hits the extension or contraction point.